# Could not connect to Azure cloud hyperscale citus

Tags: postgresql, azure

i tried connecting my local postgresql to azure via hyperscale citus but got this [error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUE2Y.png)

> psql: error: could not connect to server: could not connect to server:
>   Connection timed out (0x0000274C/10060)
>           Is the server running on host "mydemo-c.postgres.database.azure.com" (20.42.29.217) and accepting
>           TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

I tried the steps asked earlier like re-configuring conf files and making available all listening ports but it didn't worked out. Any help?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Could you please add some more information on what you tried so far with configuring conf files or whatsoever. That might give you a bigger chance on getting this issue answered/resolved.

Comment: one of the basic things that are mostly missing is the postgres.conf not having listen_ip to '*' (basically all ips). check and try that out. Also, as mentioned above please share more info with your question in order for people to help you better.

Comment: @RajVerma yes I tried wit listen_to * it didnt work out

Comment: I was trying to create a resource of hyperscale citus on azure and when i tried this command
psql "host=mydemo-c.postgres.database.azure.com port=5432 dbname=citus user=citus password={your_password} sslmode=require" to connect to my local system it gave me this error as mentioned above while i am able to connect to azure's terminal.

Comment: Connect to your local system or from your local system?? Also are you able to telnet the port from your local system? If not try then which os are you using at local? Is the firewall on? If on, have you added the port for outgoing requests? I’m afraid but there is more info needed here!